# Create a record in Edit mode

Tags: apex, pagereference, urlhacking

I am trying to open a record in Edit mode when a record type is selected. I am using the following code Im doing some mistake but dont know what.

> PageReference('/e?retURL='+Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL')+'&recordType='+RecordTypeId);

Comment: Where is the id of the record that you want to open in Edit mode?

Comment: @AslamK I am trying to create a record. My issue is there is a controller which calls different VF page based on Record type. Now I have a new record type which should have standard Page layout.

Comment: Even then you are not specifying which object you want to create. If for example it is a new Account then the pagereference should start of like `/001/e`. Similarly find the prefix of the object you want to create and accordingly modify the URL.

Answer (score 3):

You are not specifying in your URL which object you want to create the new Record for.

So assuming it is Account, it should be

`PageReference('\001\e?retURL='+Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL')+'&recordType='+RecordTypeId);`

Or alternatively create a dummy object of the required object ( say account ) and use the standard controller itself as shown below.

```
Account account = new Account();
account.RecordTypeId = someId;    
PageReference pg = new ApexPages.StandardController(account).edit();
```

Change the above for any of the other custom or standard objects.

Comment: I am getting the following error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You cannot call edit() on a null object

Comment: Then i guess the object you are passing is null. Initialize it and try.

Comment: Hey @Aslamk. The issue is I have a controller which is calling different VF page based of Record type and now I want to show a standard page layout for one record type. I tried your Account code. I inserted a record and opened the record in edit mode it is going to Infinite loop.

Comment: Try passing the `nooverride=1` parameter along with the URL and see if it works.

Comment: Hey @Aslamk thanks for the reply. I tried that it is going to default record type. I have 5 record type. 4 is using VF page and 5th one I need standard salesforce page.

Comment: @Tamil I think we are deviating from your original question. I know that you have not been able to complete your requirement yet, but it would be better if you accept this answer and ask a new question with whatever updated details you have now.

Answer (score 2):

It should have record ID before `/e`

> PageReference('{RecordID}/e?retURL='+Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL')+'&recordType='+RecordTypeId);

Comment: hi @ashwani thanks for the reply. I'm getting following error message Formula Expression is required on the action attributes.